# Typescript Types for import.meta.env

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vite

I am now using a framework (vite) that injects environment variables into `import.meta.env`.

I was previously able to create a file `env.d.ts` to provide types to `process.env`

```
declare global {
  namespace NodeJS {
    interface ProcessEnv {
      GITHUB_AUTH_TOKEN: string;
      NODE_ENV: 'development' | 'production';
      PORT?: string;
      PWD: string;
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried the following but does not work.

```
declare global {
  namespace NodeJS {
    interface ImportMeta {
      GITHUB_AUTH_TOKEN: string;
      NODE_ENV: 'development' | 'production';
      PORT?: string;
      PWD: string;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 146):

I had similar problems and solved it by

> tsconfig.json

```json
{
  ...
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "target": "ESNext",
    "types": ["vite/client"]
  }
}
```

Have `vite` installed as a dev dependency.

Comment: Works with target as es5 too

Answer (score 20):

It's documented here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-9.html#support-for-importmeta

So you're almost there:

```js
interface ImportMeta {
  env: {
    GITHUB_AUTH_TOKEN: string;
    NODE_ENV: 'development' | 'production';
    PORT?: string;
    PWD: string;
  };
}
```

But be aware that in vite all environment variables have to be prefixed with `VITE_` so neither of those environment variables are available in the application.

Comment: I'm getting ts error which I'm not sure how to fix - `All declarations of 'env' must have identical modifiers.`

Comment: Interesting, it's working for me, but I'm still using vite 1.0, maybe this changed with the new vite version 2.0 (I'm actually pretty sure that this might be the issue: https://github.com/vitejs/vite/blob/3a27fa376ea14ba31c8aa13166512b77218e2d9f/packages/vite/types/importMeta.d.ts)?

Comment: The "modifier" the error is talking about it probably `readonly` which is missing here.

Answer (score 15):

I got it to work by using the following -

```
interface ImportMetaEnv {
  VITE_PORT?: string;
  VITE_AUTH_TOKEN?: string;
}
```

Comment: Can you shed some light?, like how does env.d.ts be provided to process.env, do you just create the file or do you have to tell vite to load it somewhere?

Comment: @mentorgashi Only the `.d.ts` file is needed. There is no need to configure vite

Comment: I've followed the [docs](https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html#intellisense-for-typescript) which propose a very similar approach. Did you also have the issue with `'ImportMeta' is defined but never used.eslintno-unused-vars.`? How can I solve it?

Answer (score 10):

According to the documentation here https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html#intellisense you can do the following:

```js
// env.d.ts
interface ImportMetaEnv extends Readonly<Record<string, string>> {
  readonly VITE_APP_TITLE: string
  // more env variables...
}

interface ImportMeta {
  readonly env: ImportMetaEnv
}
```

Comment: Did you come across an eslint error `'ImportMeta' is defined but never used. eslint(no-unused-vars)`? How to solve that?

Comment: The URL to this documentation [has been updated](https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html#intellisense-for-typescript). Further, `env.d.ts` should be placed in your `src/` directory.

Answer (score 9):

The URL to this documentation linked to in the answer above [has been updated](https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html#intellisense-for-typescript).

Further, `env.d.ts` should be placed in your `src/` directory and you need a reference string at the top of the file.

A complete, working example is as follows:

```js
/// <reference types="vite/client" />

interface ImportMetaEnv {
  readonly VITE_CUSTOM_ENV_VARIABLE: string
}

interface ImportMeta {
  readonly env: ImportMetaEnv
}
```

---

#### Using a variable prefix other than `VITE_`

If you don't want to use the default variable prefix, [you can change this in your Vite config](https://vitejs.dev/config/#envprefix):

```js
{
  envPrefix: 'YOURPREFIX_',
}
```

Comment: Helped a lot. Came here from a project created from scratch. I was missing a types file (in this case, I created `env.d.ts` in the `src/` directory) and it automatically picked up `import.meta.env`. As a cherry on top, I defined my custom vars, as you did with `VITE_CUSTOM_ENV_VARIABLE `

Answer (score 3):

If you are using SvelteKit v1.0.0-next.120 and Vite 2.4.0, env must be a property of ImportMeta in global.d.ts. Here's an example:

```js
interface ImportMeta {
  env: {
    VITE_DATABASE_URL?: string
    VITE_WEB_URL?: string
    VITE_BRAINTREE_GATEWAY?: string
    VITE_BRAINTREE_DESCRIPTOR?: string
    VITE_RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY?: string
    VITE_EMAIL_FROM?: string
    VITE_EMAIL_ADMINS?: string
    VITE_SEND_IN_BLUE_KEY?: string
    VITE_SEND_IN_BLUE_URL?: string
    VITE_RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY?: string
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I faced that the example from vite's docs doesn't work if you need to **import** another type.

Say `VITE_CUSTOM_ENV_VARIABLE` is of type `MyCustomType`.

```
interface ImportMetaEnv {
  readonly VITE_CUSTOM_ENV_VARIABLE: import('./<your_path>/MyCustomType').MyCustomType

  // Optionally describe the original values from vite, needed if you remove <reference types="vite/client" /> line as I did
  readonly BASE_URL: string;
  readonly MODE: string;
  readonly DEV: boolean;
  readonly PROD: boolean;
  readonly SSR: boolean;
}

interface ImportMeta {
  readonly env: ImportMetaEnv
}
```

P.S. I also recommend to remove `/// <reference types="vite/client" />` line, because otherwise type of `VITE_CUSTOM_ENV_VARIABLE` will be `MyCustomType` or `any`;

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem trying to use environment variables using typescript with vite on React js.
I solve it on the next way, into the file "vite-env.d.ts" I put the next stuff:

```
interface ImportMeta {
  env: {
    email: string
    password: string
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest approach I found was to basically extend their class and add our keys separately:

```
// env.d.ts

/**
 * Our environment variables.
 * 
 * (See https://stackoverflow.com/a/75272079/3423324)
 */
interface ImportMetaEnvCustom extends Readonly<Record<string, string>> {
  readonly VITE_API_SERVER_HOST: string,
  readonly VITE_API_SERVER_PORT: string
}

interface ImportMeta extends import('vite/types/importMeta').ImportMeta {
  // additionally pull in the original values from vite, so you won't need <reference types="vite/client" /> any longer.
  readonly env: ImportMetaEnvCustom & import('vite/types/importMeta').ImportMetaEnv
}
```

In this example the `VITE_API_SERVER_HOST` and `VITE_API_SERVER_PORT` are now documented properly.

You also still get to keep the default Vite variables like `BASE_URL`, as well as other `meta.*` hints, like e.g. `import.meta.glob()`