# How to recognize env variables in typescript when using vite?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, environment-variables, vite

```
export const EnvironmentProvider: React.FC<EnvironmentProps> = ({ children }) => (
  <EnvironmentContext.Provider value={{
    APP_NAME: import.meta.env.VITE_APP_NAME, 
    GQL_URI: import.meta.env.VITE_GQL_URI
  }}>
    { children }
  </EnvironmentContext.Provider>
)
```

when using [import.meta to load env variables](https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html) vscode only recognize url variable... so how i can tell typescript that there are custom variables in import.meta?

Answer (score 3):

From the docs: https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html#intellisense-for-typescript

You need to create a file `env.d.ts` in your src directory (I created it in my root and it worked fine) with:

```
/// <reference types="vite/client" />

interface ImportMetaEnv {
  readonly VITE_YOUR_ENV_VAR_1: string
  readonly VITE_YOUR_ENV_VAR_2: string
  // more env variables...
}

interface ImportMeta {
  readonly env: ImportMetaEnv
}
```

"If your code relies on types from browser environments such as DOM and WebWorker, you can update the lib field in tsconfig.json" (but I didn't need this for my project)

```
{
  "lib": ["WebWorker"]
}
```

And then usage:

```
const uri import.meta.env.VITE_URI as string // I found that I still needed to type the imported var to get around https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-unsafe-assignment/
```

or in your example I think it would be:

```
export const EnvironmentProvider: React.FC<EnvironmentProps> = ({ children }) => (
  <EnvironmentContext.Provider value={{
    APP_NAME: import.meta.env.VITE_APP_NAME as string, 
    GQL_URI: import.meta.env.VITE_GQL_URI as string
  }}>
    { children }
  </EnvironmentContext.Provider>
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is what you want [智能提示](https://cn.vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html#intellisense), but only Chinese website has the section now.

In a word, you can create `/src/env.d.ts` like this:

```
interface ImportMetaEnv {
  VITE_APP_NAME: string;
  VITE_GQL_URI: string;
  // others...
}
```

Comment: english: https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html#intellisense-for-typescript

Comment: interesting too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66039933/typescript-types-for-import-meta-env

Answer (score 2):

as you would normally do with react project , create .env file in your root project and put .env in .gitignore so that you don't push important data on git by mistake .

next thing to do is that defining variable with prefix `VITE` instead of `REACT_APP` , like below

```
VITE_BASE_URL=http://localhost:7000
VITE_DB_PASSWORD=123
```

when you are done with defining your environment variable , you can use them in the project like this

```
export const BASE_URL = `${import.meta.env.VITE_BASE_URL}/api`
```

run the project and it should be working , otherwise stop the server and restart , it should solve your problem .

if you think that your problem is still not solved , you should checkout vite doc : https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@niku/vite-env-caster

This package generate types from your env file and cast environment variables to real type.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34567340)

Answer (score 0):

We ended up defining the following file:

```
// `import.meta.env[key]` would not work (see https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html#production-replacement)
export const env = {
  NODE_ENV: import.meta.env.NODE_ENV,
  API_KEY: import.meta.env.API_KEY,
}

if (typeof window === 'undefined') {
  // fail on server startup
  const missingVars = Object.keys(env).filter(key => !vars[key as keyof typeof vars])
  if (missingVars.length > 0) {
    throw Error(`Environment variables not defined: ${missingVars.join(', ')}`)
  }
}
```